# Stuck in Boot Loop

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, rom-flashing, factory-reset, reboot, boot-loop

I have an Android Jelly Bean, DOPO m7088, and its stuck in a boot loop. I did the hard resetting, wipe my data and everything and its still stuck. I've been searching the internet for weeks and haven't found anything that would work. I'm a complete noob when it comes to fooling around with a tablet. >.<... I've came across a few threads suggesting flashing the rom. I would like to try it but how do I go about it? Or should I try something else.

Oh, I've already reached out to the manufacturers and all they said is to reboot and restore to factory settings.

Please can anybody help me?

Comment: The easiest way would be telling the manufacturers you did as they said, and it didn't work. If your device is still under warranty, they should replace it (at least as long as you didn't void your warranty). I'd try that first. In case they refuse (or no more warranty), rom-flashing might help (as long as it's no hardware problem). See [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575); instructions usually come along on the respective download page.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a way to fix it. They wrote the partitions wrong. A rather [long explanation at XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=44117829) will help you fix it. I was excited to see it!

The linked post includes a detailed description to solve the issue, too much to even include an excerpt here. It includes dumping the entire ROM, fixing it on a Linux PC (using a LiveCD), and flashing back the fixed ROM to your Android device.

Comment: Link-only answers are frowned upon here: in case the link dies, they get useless. Would you please [edit] your answer and include an excerpt?

Comment: @Izzy If you look at the length of the linked page, I think you'll agree that there can't really be a useful excerpt.

Comment: In such a case, the answer should indicate that :)

Answer (score 0):

I was once struck in a boot loop and when I went to service centre, they found that it was not a software but a battery problem. Try getting it checked too.