# Redmi 4X stuck at boot loop

Tags: adb, boot-loop, xiaomi, miui, redmi

I removed some apps from my non-rooted Redmi 4X device with 'adb shell' because it was becoming very slow and unresponsive even for basic tasks. The packages I removed following [this tutorial](https://www.xda-developers.com/uninstall-carrier-oem-bloatware-without-root-access/) are:

```
santoni:/ $ pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.xiaomi.glgm                                                                                                                  
Success
santoni:/ $ pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.google.android.music                                                                                                         
Success
santoni:/ $ pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.google.android.videos                                                                                                        
Success
santoni:/ $ pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.android.email                                                                                                                
Success
santoni:/ $ pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.xiaomi.account                                                                                                               
Success
santoni:/ $ pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.xiaomi.mi_connect_service                                                                                                    
Success
santoni:/ $ pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.xiaomi.payment                                                                                                               
Success
santoni:/ $ pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.mipay.wallet.id                                                                                                              
Success
santoni:/ $ pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.mipay.wallet.in                                                                                                              
Success
santoni:/ $ pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.xiaomi.mirecycle                                                                                                             
Success
santoni:/ $ pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.miui.videoplayer                                                                                                             
Success
santoni:/ $ pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.miui.cloudsync                                                                                                               
Failure [not installed for 0]
santoni:/ $ pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.miui.player                                                                                                                  
Success
santoni:/ $ pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.miui.micloudsync                                                                                                             
Success
santoni:/ $ pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.google.android.apps.photos                                                                                                   
Success
santoni:/ $ pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.miui.hybrid                                                                                                                  
Success
santoni:/ $ pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.miui.screenrecorder                                                                                                          
Success
santoni:/ $ pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.xiaomi.scanner                                                                                                               
Success
santoni:/ $ pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.miui.securitycenter                                                                                                          
Success
santoni:/ $ pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.xiaomi.midrop                                                                                                                
Success
santoni:/ $ pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.android.thememanager                                                                                                         
Success
santoni:/ $ pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.miui.weather2                                                                                                                
Success
santoni:/ $ pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.miui.yellowpage                                                                                                              
Success
santoni:/ $
```

After I try to reboot, it is now stuck in a boot loop. How do I rectify this?
I use Arch Linux so please don't suggest any Windows-only tools that are
not available for Linux.

This phone is close to 4 years old and its battery is quite swollen, hence the screen too has come loose. Other forum threads suggest that it might be a [battery issue](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46527/stuck-in-boot-loop) however I would like to first try out anything I can do to revive this phone.

This is my first question on any stack exchange site so please forgive any errors and give me suggestions on how I can improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `com.miui.securitycenter` was the cause of the bootloop.

> As described in this article the reason for a boot loop is corrupted software/corrupted ROM

Not really. Nothing was corrupted. You just removed a system app needed for boot. I agree this package shouldn't be a boot dependency but this unfortunately is the case.

Honestly, with a Xiaomi Redmi 4X, you'd better install an AOSP ROM. Xiaomi doesn't provide security updates anymore.

I suggest you to either install [the official LineageOS version](https://download.lineageos.org/santoni) (Android 9) or the official [crDroid ROM](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/rom-official-10-0-11-0-crdroidandroid-6-x-7-x-santoni-stable.4176461/) (Android 11)

In general, if you can unlock the bootloader of your phone, go for a custom ROM. If you can't, use the [Universal Android Debloater](https://gitlab.com/W1nst0n/universal-android-debloater). The nice thing about this debloater is that the packages are documented so you can see what you can delete or not.

Comment: Thank You so much! This was the answer I was looking for. I don't want to create an MI account just to install a custom ROM. Also it is my mother's phone and I can't risk any stability issues/risks of a bricked phone.

Answer (score 1):

I reset my phone to factory settings by pressing the power and volume keys together which solved the problem of the boot loop, though it resulted in full data loss(obviously).
As described in [this article](https://lifehacker.com/how-do-i-fix-my-bricked-android-phone-5853519) the reason for a boot loop is corrupted software/corrupted ROM. Hence the best way to deal with this issue is to either reset to factory settings or install a custom ROM after 'rooting' it(as @Robert suggested).